# Method chaining from namespace

Tags: c++, oop, method-chaining

Sorry if this question causes any confusion, I am looking to implement this and do not know the right way to approach such a thing.

For one of my projects I want to implement method chaining. I want to incorporate the following functions:

```
.toVector()
.toArray()
.toBool()
...
```

I have thought about placing these inside a namespace, e.g:

```
namespace Misc {
   template<typename T, typename Inverse>

   vector<T> toVector(Inverse begin, Inverser end) {
      // ...
      // ..
   }

   // ...
   // ...
}
```

This is because there could be multiple classes, these classes MIGHT be able to use these functions, so therefore, it has to be OO rather than implementing each function again and again in different classes.

Let's say I have the following class `Wav` which reads in the data contained in a wav file:

```
class Wav {
   public:
     Wav();
     Wav(string theFileName);
     void getWaveData();
  protected:
     vector<double> data;
};
```

`data` is explicitly stored as a vector inside of the class.

In my main I want to be able to do the following:

```
int main()
{
    Wav wave("file.wav");

    int* data = wave.getWaveData().toArray(); // Method chaining to store as an array
}
```

I do not know whether or not this would be possible and if so how I would approach this without implementing all of the `Misc` functions over and over again inside each of the classes. Is there a way to communicate between the namespace and the class without having to include all of the functions over and over again?

I hope someone has a suggestion and any questions I will try to answer.

EDIT:

I have the written the following function:

```
template<typename T, typename Inverse>
T* toArray(Inverse begin, Inverse end)
{
size_t size = distance(begin, end);
auto pos = 0;

T* tmp = new T[size];

for(auto i = begin; i != end; i++)
{
    tmp[pos] = *i;
    pos++;
}
return tmp;
}
```

And if I have another function:

```
void process()
{

}
```

What would I therefore need to put inside the `params` of `process` in order to accept the following:

`int* data = process(toArray<int>(
                         std::begin(vals),
                         std::end(vals)
                    );`

This is the thing that is confusing me the most?

Comment: Why does it have to be method chaining? If you aimed for (potentially nested) function calls, it would be trivial.

Comment: @delnan Could you please give an example of what you mean?

Comment: `toBool(toArray(wave.getWaveData()))` instead of `wave.getWaveData().toArray().toBool()`.

Comment: For chaining all different classes need to inherit. I think better to not do that because it would not be good OO design as far as I know. It would lead to dependencies as well.

Comment: Since the actual work of each function would need to be different for each class, I really don't see what you hope to achieve by having them external. Have `getWaveData` and similar return a wrapper object which has the `toArray` and so on defined inside it. It would be pretty easy. You will need to be careful with scope though; looks like you'll be getting a few segfaults / invalid memory reads if you're not careful.

Comment: @delnan Thank you. I get what you mean, I will attempt to try without method chaining

Comment: @delnan Please could you see my updated posted and help me figure out where I am going wrong with the process you suggested. If you put it as an answer, I can accept it. Thank you :)

Comment: @Phorce Um, the same thing you'd put in there regardless of how how the argument value is generated? It really depends on what `process` should do, maybe the `toArray<int>(...)` call is wrong. But if the `toArray<int>(...)` part is definitely correct, it's really simple: `toArray` returns a `int *` (generally `T *` for any type `T`, but specified to be `int` at that call site), and this return value is passed as argument to `process`. You have three guesses which take `process` needs to accept for the compiler to be happy with the types ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your new function:

In order to be able to call the process method below

```
int* data = process(toArray<int>( vals.begin(), vals.end()) );
```

the parameter for the process method should match the return type of the toArray method. Perhaps you can templatize the process method too as below.

```
template<typename T>
T* process(T* t)
{
   //more code here 
   return t;
}
```

After adding the process method as above, the call to process will compile, but you will have to make the implementation of the process method generic enough to deal with different return types from other methods like toArray.